# Istio and the HTTP Host header

Tags: http-headers, istio

I have a situation where I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or if the use case is not supported by Istio at all. This is my setup:

I have a `VirtualService` connected to a `Gateway` to make some API externally available, e.g. as `api1.example.com`. The `VirtualService` is connected to some `Service` that performs some request preprocessing (some conditional URL rewriting). Now comes the tricky part: the service should forward the request to some API management solution that is running on the same cluster, in a different namespace, and *without* Istio enabled. This works in general, but I have some additional requirement that troubles me. The API management needs to know to which endpoint the request was originally sent to (to apply the correct rules), so when I forward the request from my service to the API management pod then the HTTP `Host` header should still be `api1.example.com`. This is the point where it breaks, I only get `502 Bad Gateway` errors.

Now this is the complete setup but I think you can boil it down to the following one (unfortunately, I currently don't have access to some cluster where I could create and test some minimal working example):

- `pod1` runs in `namespace1` with Istio enabled
- `pod2` runs in `namespace2` with Istio disabled and is exposed as `service2`

Now from `pod1` the following works:

```
wget -qO- http://service2.namespace2.svc.cluster.local
```

But the following does not:

```
wget -qO- --header 'Host: api1.example.com' http://service2.namespace2.svc.cluster.local
```

Any help or hints are highly appreciated!

---

Some updates following questions that were raised:

- Istio version is 1.4.6
- When I do `wget -qO- http://service2.namespace2.svc.cluster.local` than `pod2` receives the request and when I read the `Host` header then it is `service2.namespace2.svc.cluster.local`
- When I do `wget -qO- --header 'Host: api1.example.com' http://service2.namespace2.svc.cluster.local` then the request does not arrive at `pod2` at all
- `istioctl proxy-config listeners pod1` shows the following (the service in pod1 is running on port 1024, the one in pod2 is running on port 80)

```
ADDRESS            PORT      TYPE
100.96.4.131       1024      HTTP
100.96.4.131       15020     TCP
100.69.164.43      443       TCP
10.250.0.42        10250     TCP
10.250.0.47        10250     TCP
100.64.124.217     443       TCP
100.67.245.255     15011     TCP
10.250.0.46        10250     TCP
10.250.0.48        10250     TCP
10.250.0.9         10250     TCP
10.250.0.24        10250     TCP
10.250.0.50        10250     TCP
100.64.124.217     15032     TCP
100.64.0.1         443       TCP
10.250.0.108       10250     TCP
100.64.0.10        53        TCP
10.250.0.34        10250     TCP
10.250.0.8         10250     TCP
10.250.0.37        10250     TCP
100.64.124.217     15029     TCP
10.250.0.30        10250     TCP
10.250.0.36        10250     TCP
10.250.0.105       10250     TCP
100.64.124.217     15031     TCP
100.64.124.217     15030     TCP
10.250.0.92        10250     TCP
100.66.112.190     443       TCP
100.68.34.255      44134     TCP
100.64.124.217     15443     TCP
10.250.0.91        10250     TCP
10.250.0.97        10250     TCP
0.0.0.0            443       TCP
10.250.0.10        10250     TCP
10.250.0.45        10250     TCP
0.0.0.0            9943      TCP
100.64.132.219     9115      TCP
0.0.0.0            10249     TCP
100.70.99.95       443       TCP
100.65.54.197      26379     TCP
100.64.0.10        9153      TCP
0.0.0.0            9090      TCP
0.0.0.0            15014     TCP
100.71.44.89       6789      TCP
100.70.253.4       2020      TCP
0.0.0.0            9094      TCP
100.67.56.56       443       TCP
100.65.133.0       4314      TCP
0.0.0.0            4005      TCP
100.70.229.77      9411      TCP
0.0.0.0            9901      TCP
100.71.167.108     443       TCP
100.69.145.185     9093      TCP
100.70.32.142      443       TCP
100.66.233.175     42422     TCP
0.0.0.0            8080      TCP
100.69.114.203     6789      TCP
100.70.144.106     3300      TCP
0.0.0.0            20001     TCP
0.0.0.0            4004      TCP
0.0.0.0            9093      TCP
100.67.179.223     9000      TCP
100.70.18.125      3300      TCP
100.64.255.234     9090      TCP
100.66.197.157     9710      TCP
100.67.193.139     3300      TCP
100.69.114.203     3300      TCP
0.0.0.0            16909     TCP
0.0.0.0            3000      TCP
0.0.0.0            15004     TCP
100.68.54.218      9115      TCP
0.0.0.0            8060      TCP
0.0.0.0            8008      TCP
100.70.162.45      9115      TCP
0.0.0.0            15010     TCP
0.0.0.0            10054     TCP
100.65.13.208      5473      TCP
100.67.193.139     6789      TCP
100.71.44.89       3300      TCP
100.70.18.125      6789      TCP
100.67.56.56       8081      TCP
0.0.0.0            9411      TCP
0.0.0.0            2379      TCP
100.66.228.227     8081      TCP
0.0.0.0            9091      TCP
0.0.0.0            5556      TCP
100.64.124.217     15020     TCP
100.68.245.60      7000      TCP
0.0.0.0            9283      TCP
0.0.0.0            80        TCP
0.0.0.0            3100      TCP
100.66.228.227     8080      TCP
100.70.144.106     6789      TCP
0.0.0.0            1024      TCP
100.70.229.77      14268     TCP
0.0.0.0            15019     TCP
0.0.0.0            5558      TCP
100.70.229.77      14267     TCP
100.67.17.80       9100      TCP
0.0.0.0            15001     TCP
0.0.0.0            15006     TCP
100.96.1.142       443       TCP
0.0.0.0            15090     HTTP
```

Comment: Execute the following and provide the output: 
istioctl proxy-config listeners <pod>[.namespace]

Comment: what the log on pod2 in bot cases? how the first case is working if pod needs the header ?? in second request the requst will reach the pod2 with this header , can you check what header its getting there

Comment: Which istio version are You using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to communicate between istio injected service and service that is external (to istio service-mesh), You will need to use [ServiceEntry](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/service-entry/) object.

According to istio [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/service-entry/):

> `ServiceEntry` enables adding additional entries into Istio’s internal service registry, so that auto-discovered services in the mesh can access/route to these manually specified services. A service entry describes the properties of a service (DNS name, VIPs, ports, protocols, endpoints). These services could be external to the mesh (e.g., web APIs) or mesh-internal services that are not part of the platform’s service registry (e.g., a set of VMs talking to services in Kubernetes). In addition, the endpoints of a service entry can also be dynamically selected by using the `workloadSelector` field. These endpoints can be VM workloads declared using the `WorkloadEntry` object or Kubernetes pods. The ability to select both pods and VMs under a single service allows for migration of services from VMs to Kubernetes without having to change the existing DNS names associated with the services.

---

Like You mentioned:

`pod1` that runs in namespace1 with Istio enabled

`pod2` that runs in namespace2 with Istio disabled and is exposed as `service2`

In this scenario the `service2` will require a `ServiceEntry` object that will add it to Istio service mesh registry. This will allow the `service2` to be used as if it was within Istio. Note that istio features that require envoy proxy will not work for this service as it is not actually istio injected.

I suggest following this istio [Accessing External Services](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-control/) guide.

Comment: A little bit late, but I wanted to confirm that `ServiceEntry` solved the issue. I added an entry with the `host` set to "*.example.com" and then the request worked:
"wget -qO- --header 'Host: api1.example.com' http://service2.namespace2.svc.cluster.local"